# How can I find address of function that in shared object file?

Tags: linux, assembly, shared-libraries, nasm, elf

I want to write program with using NASM. Sometimes I need to use shared object file. For example libGL.so, libm.so etc. How I can find address of shared library function? And How I do it in NASM?

For example I want to use sqrt() function in libm.so. How I write .PLT and .GOT section header in nasm. Or How can I get address of sqrt() function in RAM directly? (I don't know it is possible).

Comment: Just call the functions, the linker will take care of creating the appropriate `.plt` and `.got` sections.  You may have to `call foo wrt ..plt` so it works.

Comment: @fuz Sorry I don't understand. Can you write more?

Comment: That's all there is to it. If you want to use `sqrt` then do `extern sqrt` and then `call sqrt wrt ..plt`. Obviously link with `libm`. The tools will do the rest.

Comment: @Jester I got "undefined reference to 'sqrt'"

Comment: Then you did not link with `libm`.

Comment: @Jester How can I link libm?

Comment: Depends on how you link of course. Simplest is `gcc -lm`

Comment: @Jester is "nasm test.asm -f elf64 -lm" true  for nasm?

Comment: No, nasm only produces object file. You need to link the output. `nasm test.asm -f elf64 && gcc -lm test.o`

Comment: You may also need to declare `sqrt` as `extern`.

Comment: @Jester `gcc -lm test.o` is _incorrect_. It should be `gcc test.o -lm`.

Comment: For `sqrt` specifically, you should use the asm instruction `sqrtsd xmm, xmm` or `sqrtss xmm, xmm` for Scalar Double or Single precision.  i.e. inline it.

Comment: @EmployedRussian technically yes but it works here. Only seems to matter for static libraries and objects not shared libs, although I can't find anything in the documentation about this.